# a small category equivalent to the category of all sets

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, foundations, large-cardinals

assuming grothendieck universes, is it possible to have a small category equivalent the category of all sets?

mac lane in *categories for the working mathematician* assumes the existence of a grothendieck universe set, which forms
a category $\mathbf {Set}$ of all *small* sets. skimming the book, mac lane never states this, but he seems do assume or suggest that the category of sets is somehow equivalent to $\mathbf {Set}$. but mac lane here only speaks of *metacategories* as some sort of pre-foundational mathematical objects (for instance he has a metacategory of all classes), so maybe one has to be more precise here, so:

taking as a basis an axiomatic set theory with a solid notion of classes such as neumann-gödel-bernays or morse-kelley together with the existence of a (sufficiently large) grothendieck universe set, is there a small category equivalent to the category of all sets?

Comment: If I recall correctly $\textbf{Ens}$ is defined to be a category but not necessarily closed under the same operations as $\textbf{Set}$. It may or may not be equivalent. You do not need to worry about this too much if you are just starting the subject.

Comment: @ZhenLin you are right, i updated my wording accordingly. given a set $V$, mac lane defines $\mathbf{Ens}_V$ to be the category of all sets *that are elements of $V$* with all maps between them as morphisms. in particular for the grothendieck universe $U$, we’d have $\mathbf{Ens}_U = \mathbf{Set}$. he uses $\mathbf{Ens}$ as “any one of those categories”. in any case, by the argument of atticus, none of them are equivalent to the (meta-)category of all sets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. If $C$ and $D$ are equivalent categories, then they must have the same "cardinality" of isomorphism types (ie they must either both have set-many isomorphism types, and then must have the same cardinality of these, or both have proper-class-many isomorphism types). One way of seeing this is to note that, assuming global choice, two categories are equivalent if and only if they have isomorphic [skeletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(category_theory)). Since $\mathbf{Set}$ has proper-class-many isomorphism types (one for each cardinal), it thus cannot be equivalent to a small category.